# How to inspect the properties of the :focus pseudo-class

Tags: css

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/buttons/ has an outline button with text "Primary", see attached screenshot. [image: screenshot] When I focus on the button, a shadow seems to appear but I can't find it or any of its computed properties in the developer tools. I tried toggling :focus under the :hov menu but that does not seem to help. How can I inspect the properties of the :focus pseudo-class

Comment: Because it's the `:focus-visible` state not `:focus`

Comment: Do you feel the version of browser dev tools you're using isn't relevant to mention?

Comment: @possum I tried both Chrome and Firebox latest versions but failed because I was not aware of `:focus-visible`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can right-click on the button in the Elements panel and choose "Force state" > ":focus-visible".
[image]